# jQuery Change Image src with Fade Effect

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I'm trying to create an effect where you click on a thumbnail image, and the link to the thumbnail will replace the main image, but fade it in. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$(".thumbs a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $imgURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".boat_listing .mainGallery").fadeIn(400, function() {
        $(".boat_listing .mainGallery").attr('src',$imgURL);
    });
});
```

This works and replaces the image without a fade effect. What do I need to change to get the fadeIn effect to work?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You have to make it `fadeOut()` first, or hide it.

Try this :

```
$(".thumbs a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $imgURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".boat_listing .mainGallery")
        .fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(".boat_listing .mainGallery").attr('src',$imgURL);
        })
        .fadeIn(400);
});
```

It should `fadeOut` the image, then change the `src` when it's hidden, and then `fadeIn`.

[Here's a jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/)

**Edit:** you can find a more recent & better solution in [Sandeep Pal's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16714137/515437)

Comment: Make sure you check @Sandeep Pal's for concurrent fade in/out rather than having a delay between them. If that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 37):

I think that instead of using FadeIn and fadeOut, it's better to use fadeTo functionality as
fadeIn and fadeOut created a time gap between them for few micro-seconds.

I have used above code from Sylvain : thanks to him

```
$("#link").click(function() {

  $("#image").fadeTo(1000,0.30, function() {
      $("#image").attr("src",$("#link").attr("href"));
  }).fadeTo(500,1);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I had issues with making fadeIn/fadeOut work for Firefox. This solution works for all browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I reproduced the given samples above. It gives a strange flickering, which I found that it waits for image to load after it's opacity is restored to 1. I modified the code by Sandeep.

```
$("#link").click(function() {

$("#image").fadeTo(1000,0.30, function() {
  $("#image").attr("src",$("#link").attr("href"));
  $("#image").on('load', function(){
    $("#image").fadeTo(500,1);
  });
 });
 return false;
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fade-in something that is already at 100% alpha :)

In other words, you either fade it out or hide it, and then fade it in.

I made this example, basically, I hide it and then fade it:

http://jsfiddle.net/uGFMt/