# Fadein() effect to a function: how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have this function that works well for lazy loading.

```
panel.find('img[data-src]').each(function(){
            element = $(this);
            element.attr('src', element.data('src'));
            element.removeAttr('data-src');
```

How can I give a `fadeIn()` effect to that removeAttr function?
I tried:

```
element.removeAttr('data-src').fadeIn();
```

but it doesn't work. The `img` code looks like this and I simply want the dot.png to fadeOut and the original.jpg to fade in.

```
<img src="dot.png" data-src="original.jpg">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7s1yb1un/6/
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: @NiranjanKumar as I said I want to src to fade out and the data-src to fade in when the img is in view.

Comment: Post this in jsfiddle

Comment: @NiranjanKumar here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/7s1yb1un/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s2194r8L/ try this

Comment: Did you try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16714137/1009922?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot fade a src change on an `img` element. To acheive this you'll need two `img` elements. The second one will have a the src `"original.jpg"` and will have a higher `z-index` and start with `display: none` for a style. Then you can fade it in and it will fade in over the dot.

*EDIT* Given your new question, you could do the following:

1. Add an `onload` listener for the image
2. Just before changing the "src", fade the image out
3. Then change the "src" to "original.jpg"
4. In your `onload` function, do a `fadeIn`

Comment: Is it not possible to play with the opacity 0 to the src and opacity 1 to the data-src?

Comment: @Federico Did you try my edited answer? It should do exactly what you want

Comment: I do not know hot to implement it correctly probably :/

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I have done.

Added a `fadeOut(5000)`, the img with original src will fadeout after `5 sec`.
Called a function with timeout of `6sec`, which changes the `src` with `data-src` and `fadeIn(5000)` in 5 sec, I hope this solves your problem.

JS code is below

```
var myVar;
function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ 
        var src = $("img.hide").attr("data-src");
        $("img.hide").attr("src",src);
        $("img.hide").fadeIn(5000); 
    }, 6000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").fadeOut(5000);
  myFunction();  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code would fade out, change the src, then fade in.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/o39t3fu7/5/)

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <img class="fadeable" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/767fc9c115a1b989744c755db47feb60?size=800" data-src="http://2.gravatar.com/userimage/5/ff5263e8c30557b57e64423ee8496e41?size=800" width=100 height=100 alt="smile"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('img[data-src]').each(function(i, e) {
    // cache element
    original_img = $(e);
    original_img
    .fadeOut(function(){
      original_img.attr('src', original_img.attr('data-src'))    
    })
    .fadeIn();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I found this script working (somehow), the images just blink sometimes. I don't know if semantically correct.

```
$(function() {
$('img').one("load", function() {
var e = $(this);
e.data('src', e.attr('data-src'));
e.animate({"opacity": 0}, 400);
e.data('src');
e.animate({"opacity": 1}, 400);
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code would clone the images that have the `data-src` attribute, then hide the clone, update the clone `src`, position it over the original image, and fade in. Would this work for you?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/o39t3fu7/9/)

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <img class="fadeable" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/767fc9c115a1b989744c755db47feb60?size=800" data-src="http://2.gravatar.com/userimage/5/ff5263e8c30557b57e64423ee8496e41?size=800" width=100 height=100 alt="smile"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('img[data-src]').each(function(i, e) {
    // cache element
    original_img = $(e);
    // get position of original image
    offset_left = original_img.offset().left;
    offset_top = original_img.offset().top;
    // get data-src of
    data_src = original_img.attr('data-src');
    // clone original image
    original_img.clone()
    .hide()
    // put it directly in the body, so it can be positioned
    .appendTo('body')
    // set the new src
    .attr('src', data_src)
    // place it over the original image
    .css({
        "left": offset_left,
      "top": offset_top,
      "position": "absolute"
    })
    .fadeIn(function(){
        original_img.attr('src', data_src);
        $(this).remove();
    });
  })
});
```